# How to set the size of a single symbol defined via \DeclareMathSymbol?

Tags: symbols, fontsize

I am using the following definition for a symbol I call `\nstn`:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesym}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nstn}{0}{largesym}{"22}
```

How can I set the size of this single symbol (which is basically `\varepsilon`) to a specific number (I would like it to be larger than usual/default)?

Answer (score 1):

You could just declare one symbol, and then define another using a scalebox or something...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesym}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nstnsmall}{0}{largesym}{"22}
\newcommand{\nstn}{\mathrel{\scalebox{1.5}{$\nstnsmall$}}}

\begin{document}
\[
A \nstn B
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You might change `\mathrel` to `\mathord` or `\mathop` or something depending on the mathematical syntax category. For some reason this said "relation sign" to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can by-pass NFSS and use TeX primitives:

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareFixedFont{\nstnfont}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}{14.5pt}
\newfam\nstnfam
\textfont\nstnfam=\nstnfont
\makeatletter
\set@mathsymbol\nstnfam\nstn\mathbin{22}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[ A \nstn B \]
\end{document}
```